# General purpose migrations

Tags: android, migration, sharedpreferences

I like to migrate various things from one version to another in an Android app.
My concrete migrations are all ready and working fine. I migrate sharedPrefences, compress images a little more and things like that.

But I can't think of handling:

1. Running every migration only once elegantly. (Did it with a shared.-pref MIGRATION_v1_DONE so far).
2. Do not run migrations for new installs.

I found this project [here](https://github.com/freeletics/migrator). It is nice as it is running every Migration only once and if I exit with an exception the Migration will run again as it is not completed yet.

**But this project will also run migrations for new installs as well.** So I need to add checks and more checks to every migration. Very error prone. I would like to use the library but not for new installs.

I was thinking of something like:

1. Migration class file for version 1 to 2.
2. New installs are already version 2 and will not be migrated.
3. In the future a class file for version 2 to 3.
4. New installs are already version 3 and will not be migrated.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a MigrationFactory class and for every migration it's own class extended from an abstract class which has #migrate function.

The whole migration works by reading and writing the **BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE** constant. At first run (new install in introduction of MigrationFactory) this is 0. A loop iterates from 0 to current VERSION_CODE and a switch case gets into action when an iteration matches a case.

On first run case 0 is matched. In my construct this checks a sharedPref value is existing. If not the case the app is **new installed and no migration is needed**, int i will be set to current VERSION_CODE, switch case left by break, for loop left my break. If sharedPref is found (**the app was installed and is just updated**) the loop continuous 1, 2, 3... ohh 54 - case matches and runs V54Migration#migrate.

Let's say BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE is currently 72. V72Migration is not run. It will be run on BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE = 73! During some future release another migration could be needed on VERSION_CODE = 77. This will be run on a release with VERSION_CODE 78.

For somebody with a very old version of the app (VERSION_CODE before update = 10) and now the app is VERSION_CODE 75 **migrations 54, 71 and 72 will be run**.

```
public class MigrationFactory {

private static final String CURRENT_VERSIONCODE = "current_versioncode";
// ...

private void setVersionCode(int versionCode) {
    PrefManager.with(mContext).save(CURRENT_VERSIONCODE, versionCode);
}

public boolean isMigrationNeeded() {
    return getVersionCode() < BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
}

private int getVersionCode() {
    //Empty during first run. Will return 0 instead.
    return PrefManager.with(mContext).getInt(CURRENT_VERSIONCODE, 0);
}

public void createMigration() {
    for (int i = getVersionCode(); i < BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                if (!mContext.getSharedPreferences(mContext.getPackageName())
                     .contains("a string only existent in an already installed version")})) {
                    Log.d(MainApplication.getTAG(this.getClass()), "I am a V0_NewInstall");
                    //if new install set i to current VERSION_CODE, no
                    //migrations needed in that case.
                    i = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
                    //Now exist out the loop and switch case.
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 54:
                new V54_CropJPGAvatarImages(mContext).migrate();
                break;
            case 71:
                new V71_CompressJPG(mContext).migrate();
                break;
            case 72:
                new V72_SetWhatever(mContext).migrate();
                break;
            case 77:
                break;
        }
    }
    setVersionCode(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE);
}
}
```

I call this class in my MainApplication#onCreate:

```
MigrationFactory migrationFactory = MigrationFactory.getInstance(this);
    if (migrationFactory.isMigrationNeeded())
        migrationFactory.createMigration();
```